# Control-P5 - Slider values not displaying correctly

Tags: processing, control-p5

I have a processing sketch which includes a slider. The code that generates this slider is below:

```java
ControlP5 gui;
gui = new ControlP5(this);
gui.addSlider("Tolerance").setPosition(40, height-60).setSize(400, 20).setRange(0.00, 0.10).setValue(0.05).setNumberOfTickMarks(11).setSliderMode(Slider.FLEXIBLE);
gui.getController("Tolerance").getValueLabel().align(ControlP5.RIGHT, ControlP5.TOP_OUTSIDE).setPaddingX(0).setFont(font);
gui.getController("Tolerance").setCaptionLabel("Comparison Tolerance");
gui.getController("Tolerance").getCaptionLabel().align(ControlP5.LEFT, ControlP5.TOP_OUTSIDE).setPaddingX(0).setFont(font);
```

The problem I have is that the value `0.08` is displayed when the slider is at both the `0.08` `TickMark` and the `0.09` `TickMark`. `0.09` is the only value which displays incorrectly - see the below pictures:

[image: Image1]

[image: Image2]

[image: Image3]

[image: Image4]

The slider is actually selecting the correct value of `0.09` in the third image above, when the position of the slider is printed to the console, but this display error is confusing and not ideal. Any help would be much appreciated.

**UPDATE:** I have since discovered that the value displayed to the top right of the slider is always rounded **down**. When outputting the slider value to the console, the values are usually minutely different to what is intended - i.e. at the center position, the actual slider value printed to the console is `0.0500003`. From looking at the true value for each slider position, the `0.09` position is the only one with a value under the intended value - `0.0899996`. Therefore, it appears this is rounded down to `0.08` to display the value. So the question still stands - is there a way to display the correct value of `0.09`, given this information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well spotted! Perhaps you should post an issue for the developer.
In the meantime, what you can do is subclass the Slider class and use Java's [DecimalFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) class to fix the label:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import controlP5.*;

ControlP5 gui;

void setup(){
  size(640,480);
  gui = new ControlP5(this);
  CustomSlider slider = new CustomSlider(gui,"Tolerance");

  slider.setPosition(40, height-60).setSize(400, 20).setRange(0.00, 0.10).setValue(0.05);
  slider.setFont(createFont("Verdana",12));
  slider.setNumberOfTickMarks(11).setSliderMode(Slider.FLEXIBLE);
  slider.getValueLabel().align(ControlP5.RIGHT, ControlP5.TOP_OUTSIDE).setPaddingX(0);
  slider.setCaptionLabel("Comparison Tolerance");
  slider.getCaptionLabel().align(ControlP5.LEFT, ControlP5.TOP_OUTSIDE).setPaddingX(0);
}
void draw(){
  background(0);
}

//subclass slider
public class CustomSlider extends Slider{

  //decimal format reference
  DecimalFormat df;

  //constructor
  public CustomSlider( ControlP5 cp5 , String name ) {
    super(cp5,name);
    //setup decimal format proof of concept - hardcoded fractional digits for now (this can be nicer)
    df = new DecimalFormat();
    df.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
  }

  @Override public Slider setValue( float theValue ) {
    super.setValue(theValue);
    //this can be improved, follow the CP5 component lifecycle to determine when an instance initialised in the constructor is ready
    if(df != null){
      _myValueLabel.set( df.format(getValue( )));
    }else{
      _myValueLabel.set( getValue( ) +"" );
    }
    return this;
  }

}
```

[image: preview]

Comment: I think I might - seems a bit sloppy! Thanks for this - nice solution. I'll go with that for now cheers!

Comment: Remember that Processing is aimed (mostly) at designers/artists/creatives/etc., and precision probably isn't a priority. The library itself, as it is, is a pretty decent undertaking for a single person and a great contribution to the community. Of course there is room for improvement, but this where we could also help :)

Comment: True - perhaps that was a tad harsh! It is a very impressive library, but here the issue was less about precisions and more about the graphics - the output is correct (0.899996) for the purposes of calculation, but the graphic output (arguably the priority here as you say), was problematic. Anyway - thanks very much for the help and I'll let the dev know :)